# Is the amount of Skill points per level right?

Tags: starfinder, skills

Following official rules about skills that state: "Your skill ranks in a single skill can’t exceed your total character level."
And some classes granting 8 + Int modifier per level, wouldn't those characters become some jack of all trades demigods?
Is it right that a character (by example) starting with 11 points have at least (disconsidering trained class skill) 11 different skills first rank?
I havent played Pathfinder, so I dont know how this will behave.

Comment: Welcome to this Stack! Take the [tour]. It seems like you're looking for confirmation that rules work a certain way, and that's totally legit, but it might be useful to phrase the question so that you'll get a useful answer that solves what you think might be the problem. *Do PCs routinely overcome challenges they probably shouldn't because of their wide variety of skills?* or *How does a GM challenge such omnicompetent PCs?*, for example. As it stands, I'm not sure what an answer will say after *Yes.* `:-)` Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: It's worth noting that most classes only get 4 or 6 +INT skills per level, and those classes my not have a very high INT score; if you have a 4+1 skills per level, choosing which ones to specialize in becomes a lot more difficult and you might start appreciating (or resenting) the Operative or Envoy that is able to get through the trickier situations.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I'm still beginning in this system and haven't finished reading the book yet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

That is indeed how it works.